# DoubleClick/YieldManager/Ad.com Tracking Pixels - What exactly do they track?

Tags: analytics

Our marketing team has placed a lot of these tracking pixels on our site. Most of them just make a simple HTTP GET to a URL, usually by using a IMG tag, but some document.write in an iframe/script node as well.

What I would like to know, is what exactly these track. Source IP? What if you are behind a proxy?

Comment: Not a programming question. Why don't you ask your marketing team? Or your service providers?

Comment: I'm looking at it from a programming perspective, the marketing team wouldn't know what it does either. I want to know how they work.

Answer (score 1):

These sites cause the visitors browser to go to the site to load the image or javascript. What the site does is store a cookie and/or fingerprint of the visitor. Your site also tells the tracking site something about the visitor -- whether they purchased something or particular aspects of the pages that were vistited. The tracking site than can connect this visit with other visits to your sites, other sites, banner ads or more.

Answer (score 0):

It's called a [Web bug](http://www.google.ca/search?q=web+bug).